# How to get object field for max value in another field in grouped by one more field?

Tags: java, java-stream, java-11

I have list of entities that looks like this:

```
class History {
    public String code;
    public Integer version;
    public LocalDateTime creationDate;
}
```

For each code with max version I wanna to get creationDate. I did it like this, but I think that it can be done somehow easier...

```
Map<String, History> historyMaxVersion = histories.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(History::getCode, Function.identity(),
               BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(History::getVersion))));

Map<String, LocalDateTime> historiesLastUpdatedDates = historyMaxVersion.entrySet().stream()
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> entry.getValue()
                        .getCreationDate()));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this:

After grouping by each `code` then use `collectingAndThen` collectors and find max item based on `version` amount and at the end use `map` to extract `creationCode`.

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.collectingAndThen;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.maxBy;

Map<String, LocalDateTime> result = histories.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(History::getCode,
            collectingAndThen(maxBy(Comparator.comparing(History::getVersion)),
                  history -> history.map(History::getCreationDate).orElse(null))));
```